# How to create a list of tuples without each pair being converted to string in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to create a list of tuples for further elaborations in RF, but only manage to have a list of strings using the `Create List` keyword:

```
*** Test cases ***
Tuple list test
    @{tuples_list}=     Create List             ('1','one')     ('2','two')     ('3','three')
    Log     ${tuples_list}
```

This way each tuple is a string, as it looks in the log:

> ["('1','one')", "('2','two')", "('3','three')"]

Is it possibile to create a list of tuples without each pair being converted to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use robot's new (as of 3.2) [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation) feature:

```
@{tuples_list}=  Set variable  ${{ [('1', 'one'), ('2', 'two'), ('3', 'three')] }}
```

-or-

```
@{foo}=  Create list
...  ${{ ('1', 'one') }}
...  ${{ ('2', 'two') }}
...  ${{ ('3', 'three') }}
```

Comment: The first example will create a tuple of tuples (e.g. immutable) while OP asked for a list.

Comment: @TodorMinakov: thanks for pointing that out. Oddly, when I ran the code `tuples_list` was a mutable list. However, I've updated the example to explicitly create a list.